# Printing the dictionary sorted by value

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to print the dictionary sorted by its `value` in this code portion:

```
for key,value in frequency.items():
    output = key + ' : ' + str(value)

sorted_output = sorted(output.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
print sorted_output
```

When I try to run the program, I get the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 16, in <module>
    sorted_output = sorted(output.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'
```

How can I solve this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Your `for` loop is making lots of strings, assigning them to `output`, and then throwing them away as they get overwritten the the next time through the loop.

Comment: What is `output` meant to be?

Comment: You are using the wrong variable name. Please proofread your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are converting the key value pair to string and string doesn't have .items() . So it is giving the error.

Try this:

```
from operator import itemgetter    
for k, v in sorted(frequency.items(), key=itemgetter(1)):
        print k, v
```